# Guardar os valores dos ingressos somando ao montante existente

Tags: portugol, visualg

> Crie um fluxograma que leia do usuário o valor de um ingresso e no final mostre: o total da arrecadação e quantos ingressos foram vendidos. O fluxograma só deve parar ao digitar zero no valor do ingresso.

Ele precisa armazenar nas variáveis `totval` e `totquant` até que digite `0` no valor para terminar e mostrar o valor de ingressos vendidos e a quantidade.

```
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
val,quant,totval,totquant : real

Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc...
totval <- 0
totquant <- 0
repita

escreval("Qual valor do ingresso: ")
leia(val)
escreval("Quantos ingressos: ")
leia(quant)

totval <- val*quant
totquant <-quant


até val = 0
escreval ("valor total de ingressos é: ",totval)
escreval ("Quantidade de ingressos vendido é: " ,totquan
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer uma acumulação e está descartando o valor anterior em cada atribuição nas variáveis. Para acumular você tem que pegar o valor atual da variável e somar com o novo valor que deseja acumular.

```
Var
    val, quant, totval, totquant : real
Inicio
    totval <- 0
    totquant <- 0
    repita
        escreval("Qual valor do ingresso: ")
        leia(val)
        escreval("Quantos ingressos: ")
        leia(quant)
        totval <- totval + val * quant
        totquant <- totquant + quant
    até val = 0
    escreval ("valor total de ingressos é: ", totval)
    escreval ("Quantidade de ingressos vendido é: " , totquan)
Fim
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Loop.ptg).